# Writing One Shell script to first enter nix shell, then enter the python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nix, nixos

I want to schedule a job from wsl. The job will need to be run in the nix-shell and then in the python virtual environment under Nix-shell. I try to do this by writing a shell script, run `./enter.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
nix-shell -p python38Full python38Packages.virtualenv;
source .venv/bin/activate
```

However, it doesn't enter the

```
(virt)
[nix-shell:xxx]
```

after I run `./enter.sh`. I need to first run the first line, then run the second line separately.
It would be super helpful if someone knows a way to write a shell script that can do these two steps by running one script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell scripts are a bit different from interactive sessions in the terminal.

When you run `nix-shell` in your terminal, the original shell process creates a `nix-shell` process and lets it read your input until `nix-shell` exits, returning control to the original shell.

In a shell script on the other hand, the shell will read all lines by itself and will not delegate the processing of the shell script to other executables like `nix-shell`. *

If you want to run all commands in the `nix-shell`, you can use a special shebang at the top of the file. For example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -p python38Full -p python38Packages.virtualenv
#!nix-shell -i bash
source .venv/bin/activate

# insert commands to be run here
```

`/usr/bin/env` is just a helper to look up `nix-shell` without an absolute path.
`nix-shell` is run as a script interpreter that will parse `#!nix-shell` lines for its own options.
The `-i bash` option tells it to invoke `bash` as the actual interpreter for this script.
`bash` ignores the shebang and `#!nix-shell` lines, because they're comments. `nix-shell` has set the right environment variables in advance. It continues to source the activate file.

You might want to generate the activate script before running `source`, but I suppose that depends on your workflow.

Alternatively, you could use the `--run COMMAND` option of `nix-shell` to run single commands in the context provided by Nix.

---

*: commands in parentheses do run in a separate process, but this is mostly an implementation detail. It won't let other programs take over the execution of the script.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the answer. 
I am still a little confused, so do?es it mean after the line `#!nix-shell -i bash`, I can write the command for nix-shell? Since I ran the script you posted, and I didn't enter either nix shell or the virtual env.   
In your suggestion, shall I generate a script with only `source .venv/bin/activate` in it ? Additionally, I was trying to have `--run python start.py` , but it was showing `line 5: --run: command not found.` Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: The way I understood it is that you want to write a shell script, so not interactive. If you want to enter a Nix shell in the terminal that automatically loads virtualenv, you could write a `shell.nix` file with a `shellHook` that loads the virtualenv. See https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#description-13

Comment: Thank you. This solves the exact problem we were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this issue today, looked at what nix-shell docs had to say as suggested in the comments, and came up with a solution. I found NixOS Wiki helpful as well (see: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell).

You can either enter the environment automatically with direnv (see: https://nix.dev/guides/recipes/direnv.html and https://github.com/nix-community/nix-direnv?tab=readme-ov-file#direnv-source_url) or use a one liner flow:

- Seamlessly initialize with direnv, by following the nix-direnv install steps above and adding a file like the example below named `.envrc`:

```bash
if ! has nix_direnv_version || ! nix_direnv_version 3.0.4; then
  source_url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nix-community/nix-direnv/3.0.4/direnvrc" "sha256-DzlYZ33mWF/Gs8DDeyjr8mnVmQGx7ASYqA5WlxwvBG4="
fi
use_nix
```

- Or initialize virtualenv with `nix-shell`:

```bash
# nix-shell looks for shell.nix
nix-shell
# You are now using virtualenv
(venv)
[nix-shell:~/example-repo]$ python --version
Python 3.9.16
```

Below is an example `shell.nix` file:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  # nativeBuildInputs is usually what you want -- tools you need to run
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs.buildPackages; [
    python39Full
    python39Packages.virtualenv
  ];
  shellHook = ''
    virtualenv --python="${pkgs.python39Full}/bin/python" ./venv
    source ./venv/bin/activate
  '';
}
```